# how to solve rsmq queue already exits error while creating queue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, publish-subscribe

I am implementing a redis pubsub service using rsmq package. The `createQueue` function returns queue already exists although the `listQueues` function is showing any such queue and is returning an empty array. Also there is no function in the code to delete a queue from redis.

```js
rsmq.listQueues(function (err, queues) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err)
        return;
    }
    console.log("Active queues: " + queues.join( "," ) )
    console.log(queues); // EMPTY ARRAY
    if(!queues.includes(queueName)){
        rsmq.createQueue({ qname: queueName }, function (err, resp) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err) // throwing error "queue already exists"
                return
            }
            if (resp === 1) {
                console.log("queue created")
            }
        });    
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
rsmq.deleteQueue({ qname: "myqueue" }, function (err, resp) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err)
        return
    }

    if (resp === 1) {
        console.log("Queue and all messages deleted.")
    } else {
        console.log("Queue not found.")
    }
});
```

code to delete the queue
Refer - https://www.npmjs.com/package/rsmq for more about rsmq